# vNext: Form method POST not working with Debian/Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I trying to build up simple ASP.NET vNext application.

I have simple client-side html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/Home/Login" method="post">
    Login: <input type="text" name="login"><br>
    Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And I have simple server-side code to handle POST action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login(string login, string password)
    {
        if (Validate(login, password))
        {
            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, login) };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            Context.Response.SignIn(identity);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }
```

With Windows/IIS Express it works fine, with Debian/Kestrel it not works, server method Login in not invoked.

So, my question is - how make it work with Debian?

Comment: "Debian/Kestrel it not works, server method Login in not invoked." Much more information, pls.

Comment: I make http post call to the  Login method, but Login method in my Home controller is not invoking. I started experimenting with content-type - with text/plain it working, with application/x-www-form-urlencoded not

Comment: what about using `@Html.BeginForm` to generate the form element, will it work?

Comment: just in case is a path issue, change `<form action="/Home/Login" method="post">` to this `<form action="~/Home/Login" method="post">` ~ added.

Comment: @brewerof: what if you comment out all the code except the redirect? My guess is your post could just raise an error that causes the pipeline to fail.